# Parse RSS content into native UWP XAML TextBlock and Image controls

Tags: c#, parsing, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, rss-reader

I am writing an uwp app for reading RSS feeds. I parse the URL into RSS elements with Microsoft RSS Parser. But the content is in a big HTML p tag and have bold and italic style and with img tag too. I looked and most RSS app just use webview for that part of their app. I want it to look native, but most HTML Parser does not respect the ordering of paragraphs since they just search for nodes.

My question is, should I write my own Parser that only fit this specific needs and breaks/need to be repaired every time the site changes? Or is there a better option that I am currently too blind to see?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you could write your own Parser. RSS is XML-formatted plain text. The styles might be changed frequently, but the main XML elements of the content might not change frequently. You could use the [Windows.Web.Syndication namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/web-feeds) API to get every item.

Then, you could make your own XAML UI layout with the Textblock, Image etc. controls. I believe it will make your UI looks more beautiful instead of showing it in webview directly.

Here's a UWP [Syndication sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Syndication) for your details.